# Error/Exception while listing the AWS S3 files

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I get an Exception while listing the S3 files.

```
**"Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object."**
```

Below is my Code :

```
do
{
    Console.Write(HashS3Objects.Count+"\t\t\r" );
    try
    {
        listResponse = client.ListObjects(listRequest);
        foreach (S3Object obj in listResponse.S3Objects)
        {
            try
            {
                HashS3Objects.Add(obj.Key, obj);
            }
            catch (Exception ex1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex1.Message);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex1) **// This catch block catches the exception**
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex1.Message);
    }
    listRequest.Marker = listResponse.NextMarker;
} while (listResponse.IsTruncated);
```

The line  listResponse = client.ListObjects(listRequest); throws the exception.

Comment: What's the type of `client` and what's the full stack trace?

Comment: using (AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client(AWSAccessKeyId, AWSSecretAccessKey, S3Config))